# Set Initial Height for Resizable Text Area with Large Initial Value

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a text area element that I want to cap at an initial height of `168px` that is expandable vertically but has an initial value that's large and is auto-expanding the box past that `168px` initial height on page load.  I want to be able to allow the user to be able to expand that box if they want to later on but initially on page load it should be set to `168px` with the overflow from that initial value hidden.  Have tried various combinations of `min-height`, `resize: vertical`, and `overflow` without success.  The box is still autoexpanding as the initial value gets loaded into it on page load.  Is this possible with CSS?

Comment: You can use max-height:168px;

Comment: setting `max-height: 168px` makes it so the box isn't expandable past `168px` unfortunately.  I still want it to be expandable if the user chooses to do so.

Comment: Please share minimal code which has the problem.Then I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, this code will work. Please share your code as a snippet, it would be easy to debug.

```css
textarea{
  resize:vertical;
  min-height:168px;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: this seems to work with just CSS; I wonder if my issue is more with react.  It looks like react is adding an inline style attribute with height set to something else by default on page load.

Comment: Please share your code after react adding those inline style attribute. With CSS we can override elements upto some extent

Comment: looks like my issue was related to react; this answer is correct though in pure CSS - thank you